# WP3 manual excerpt not showing up

Tags: php, wordpress-theming

im struggling with some wordpress theme code, my goal is to create a list of posts based on a specific category, content of these posts should be the manual excerpt's using the excerpt field for posts.

my problem is, no matter what i do my theme continues to show an automated excerpts and tottaly rejects my manual version, like the manual excerpts is disabled or something, i've been googling it for ages but can't find any solutions.

any suggestions ?

**data:**
WP version 3.5.1
theme: from scratch

i have this code in my category.php

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="listview_page_header">
    <p> <?php echo single_cat_title( '', false ); ?></a>
</div>


<?php
query_posts('cat=3');
while(have_posts()) : the_post();
?>
<ul>
<li><h3><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
<ul><li><?php the_excerpt(); ?></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php //get_footer(); ?>
```

//M

Comment: The code looks fine, have you got anything related to `the_excerpt` in your `functions.php` file?

Comment: ahhhh i found there's a function overwriting the get_the_excerpt, im guessing that the_excerpt is connected to this somehow. it's working after removing these function in my function.php.. no i just need to find a way to remove the p tag the_excerpts automatically add's... this is a stupied idea from WP's side grrr

Comment: to remove the p tags from your excerpt's you can do the following :)..<p class="btn"> <?php remove_filter('the_excerpt', 'wpautop'); the_excerpt(); ?> </p> ENJOY.